# Make graphs based on Excel data

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm not that into Illustrator, so this might be a easy thing to do.

I would like to create thousand of graphs (eg. pie charts) based on rows of data in Excel.

Something like this:

1. Create some sort of template.
2. Import data. Directly from the Excel-file or via CSV.
3. Make chart files, based on the template. Generate 1 file per row.

The first column in the Excel, could be a customer number that sets the filename.

Is this possible.

Btw:
The goal is to link the graphs to an InDesign template where the customer number tells InDesign what file to link to the current post.

Comment: This is non-trivial.  Will require some Illustrator JavaScripting.  Doesn't Excel have some pie-chart facilities?  When I need quick and dirty charts, I use Apple's Numbers, which isn't wonderful, but at least the graphics are sexy.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible, if you want to make a graph then hit "J" and start making any kind of graph. But doing in batch might be possible using javascript.